# Shopify Data Population

Tags: shopify, shopify-template, shopify-api, dummy-data

As a Developer, I want to add the dummy data to store. When I Add my theme to a new store, I want to populate all data as it is, like the previous store, images, navigations, collections, products, pages, etc.
is there any way to do this in Shopify without any app?

Answer (score 1):

It is really quite easy.

Use brew or your favorite tool to install the Shopify CLI tool. Using that you can log in to your development store, with your partner account.

There is a command you run, labeled **populate**. So you can do this:

```
shopify populate orders
shopify populate products
```

and get your development store loaded with data.

Comment: Hi @David Lazar. thanks for your answer, but actually my clients want the same data of blogs, pages, etc. He wants when he adds the current Shopify theme to any new store, all data populate over the new store like an old store. pages, blogs, menus should add to the new store as it is. thanks

Comment: That is trivial to do. Make data, transfer to store. Have fun.